# Does localstack support MSK Connector with Custom Plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, localstack, aws-msk

I am currently using an MSK connector with a custom plugin written in Java to consume a Kafka topic and send it to s3 on AWS. However, due to limited permissions (read-only access), it is challenging to test the setup. I am considering using LocalStack to perform local testing.

I referred to the LocalStack documentation (https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/coverage/coverage_kafka/) to check if MSK connectors are supported. However, I couldn't find any mention of the connector in the list, and it was not greyed out like other unsupported functions typically are in the list. This lack of mention and absence of grey-out indication have left me confused about whether LocalStack supports MSK connectors or if there is another term being used.

After spending hours searching and seeking advice from others, it seems that LocalStack does not support MSK connectors, let alone MSK connectors with custom plugins.

I have two questions:

1. Can LocalStack support MSK connectors with custom plugins?
2. Are there any other sources or documentation that provide a clearer understanding of what LocalStack can and cannot do? The official documentation seems vague, and my team and I have had to rely on trial and error to test its capabilities.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: You can use standalone kafka container, Minio, and S3 sink connector all locally. MSK or localstack isn't needed